# A status of 500 error occurs in Magento 2.2 production mode

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, magento2.2.6

Yesterday, I switched from developer mode to production mode.

After changing the mode, I used the following command:.

```
# /usr/local/php71/bin/php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production --skip-compilation
# chown -R fascinate:www-data /var/www/html/primary
# find /var/www/html/primary -type f -print0 | xargs -r0 chmod 664
# find /var/www/html/primary -type d -print0 | xargs -r0 chmod 775
# /usr/local/php71/bin/php  bin/magento setup:upgrade
# /usr/local/php71/bin/php bin/magento setup:di:compile
# chown -R fascinate:www-data /var/www/html/primary
# /usr/local/php71/bin/php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
# /usr/local/php71/bin/php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy ja_JP
# chown -R fascinate:www-data /var/www/html/primary
# find /var/www/html/primary -type f -print0 | xargs -r0 chmod 664
# find /var/www/html/primary -type d -print0 | xargs -r0 chmod 775
# chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/primary/var/session
```

An error occurred when accessing the front end.

The following contents were written.

```
2019/06/13 15:46:21 [error] 27980#27980: *40 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '<' in /var/www/html/primary/var/view_preprocessed/pub/static/app/design/frontend/Infortis/base/Infortis_Base/templates/product/list_featured_slider.phtml on line 1" while reading response header from upstream, client: 51.75.170.163, server: primary.development-ecommerce.com, request: "GET /english/?SID=m5rdn5o00j52d9n0u1ps52mmcu HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9071", host: "primary.development-ecommerce.com", referrer: "https://160.16.4.169/english/"
```

I don't know what the cause is.

Could you help me?

Comment: add `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and `ini_set('display_errors',1);` in `index.php` file to get the actual error on browser.

Comment: Added logged error messages.

Comment: error is in this file app/design/frontend/Infortis/base/Infortis_Base/templates/product/list_featured_slider.phtml add the code above

Comment: When I checked the template, I found a problem in the code. The problem has been corrected. Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have an additional "<" on php starting tag https://cl.ly/c311d56d61f2 , remove the "<"

```
From <<?php to <?php
```

Comment: When I checked the template, I found a problem in the code. The problem has been corrected. Thank you for your advice.

Comment: @mr.hironobu Can you mark as an useful answer, thank you :) , glad you solve it

Answer (score 0):

500 error code means syntax error. If you found 500 error than first check syntax. 
These are error codes.

> 100 => 'Continue',
>
> 101 => 'Switching Protocols',
>
> 102 => 'Processing', // WebDAV; RFC 2518
>
> 200 => 'OK',
>
> 201 => 'Created',
>
> 202 => 'Accepted',
>
> 203 => 'Non-Authoritative Information', // since HTTP/1.1
>
> 204 => 'No Content',
>
> 205 => 'Reset Content',
>
> 206 => 'Partial Content',
>
> 207 => 'Multi-Status', // WebDAV; RFC 4918
>
> 208 => 'Already Reported', // WebDAV; RFC 5842
>
> 226 => 'IM Used', // RFC 3229
>
> 300 => 'Multiple Choices',
>
> 301 => 'Moved Permanently',
>
> 302 => 'Found',
>
> 303 => 'See Other', // since HTTP/1.1
>
> 304 => 'Not Modified',
>
> 305 => 'Use Proxy', // since HTTP/1.1
>
> 306 => 'Switch Proxy',
>
> 307 => 'Temporary Redirect', // since HTTP/1.1
>
> 308 => 'Permanent Redirect', // approved as experimental RFC
>
> 400 => 'Bad Request',
>
> 401 => 'Unauthorized',
>
> 402 => 'Payment Required',
>
> 403 => 'Forbidden',
>
> 404 => 'Not Found',
>
> 405 => 'Method Not Allowed',
>
> 406 => 'Not Acceptable',
>
> 407 => 'Proxy Authentication Required',
>
> 408 => 'Request Timeout',
>
> 409 => 'Conflict',
>
> 410 => 'Gone',
>
> 411 => 'Length Required',
>
> 412 => 'Precondition Failed',
>
> 413 => 'Request Entity Too Large',
>
> 414 => 'Request-URI Too Long',
>
> 415 => 'Unsupported Media Type',
>
> 416 => 'Requested Range Not Satisfiable',
>
> 417 => 'Expectation Failed',
>
> 418 => 'I\'m a teapot', // RFC 2324
>
> 419 => 'Authentication Timeout', // not in RFC 2616
>
> 420 => 'Enhance Your Calm', // Twitter
>
> 420 => 'Method Failure', // Spring Framework
>
> 422 => 'Unprocessable Entity', // WebDAV; RFC 4918
>
> 423 => 'Locked', // WebDAV; RFC 4918
>
> 424 => 'Failed Dependency', // WebDAV; RFC 4918
>
> 424 => 'Method Failure', // WebDAV)
>
> 425 => 'Unordered Collection', // Internet draft
>
> 426 => 'Upgrade Required', // RFC 2817
>
> 428 => 'Precondition Required', // RFC 6585
>
> 429 => 'Too Many Requests', // RFC 6585
>
> 431 => 'Request Header Fields Too Large', // RFC 6585
>
> 444 => 'No Response', // Nginx
>
> 449 => 'Retry With', // Microsoft
>
> 450 => 'Blocked by Windows Parental Controls', // Microsoft
>
> 451 => 'Redirect', // Microsoft
>
> 451 => 'Unavailable For Legal Reasons', // Internet draft
>
> 494 => 'Request Header Too Large', // Nginx
>
> 495 => 'Cert Error', // Nginx
>
> 496 => 'No Cert', // Nginx
>
> 497 => 'HTTP to HTTPS', // Nginx
>
> 499 => 'Client Closed Request', // Nginx
>
> 500 => 'Internal Server Error',
>
> 501 => 'Not Implemented',
>
> 502 => 'Bad Gateway',
>
> 503 => 'Service Unavailable',
>
> 504 => 'Gateway Timeout',
>
> 505 => 'HTTP Version Not Supported',
>
> 506 => 'Variant Also Negotiates', // RFC 2295
>
> 507 => 'Insufficient Storage', // WebDAV; RFC 4918
>
> 508 => 'Loop Detected', // WebDAV; RFC 5842
>
> 509 => 'Bandwidth Limit Exceeded', // Apache bw/limited extension
>
> 510 => 'Not Extended', // RFC 2774
>
> 511 => 'Network Authentication Required', // RFC 6585
>
> 598 => 'Network read timeout error', // Unknown
>
> 599 => 'Network connect timeout error', // Unknown